# SSH login to Cisco switch using Rancid times out

Tags: ssh, cisco, rancid

I have a 3560 switch that I have configured to accept SSH logins, and this works fine. However I cannot get Rancid to complete the login process to any of my switches using SSH. I get a timeout error after a minute or so. Telnet logins work fine with the same username and password.

Here is my rancid setup in .cloginrc:

```
add user * {myuser}
add password * {strongAccessPassword}  {strongEnablePassword}
add method * ssh telnet
```

Then, when I run bin/clogin 10.10.1.10 I get:

```
# bin/clogin 10.10.1.10
10.10.1.10
spawn ssh -c 3des -x -l myuser 10.10.1.10

###############################################
Please authenticate.
###############################################

Password: 
Error: TIMEOUT reached
```

Again, when I do this using telnet as my preferred mothod in .cloginrc, it works without issue.

Comment: By the way, someone should feel free to add the "rancid" tag, I couln't add it myself since I'm a newb.

Comment: It looks like rancid failing at parsing the switch' answer. Does rancid works if you choose telnet? What is the output of manually connecting to the switch? Does it prompt for a username?

Comment: Yes, the test works without issue using telnet. Also, the command: ssh -c 3des -x -l myuser 10.10.1.10 works if I run it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this when the SSH server's responses confuse RANCID's `clogin` script in some way - it doesn't realize that it's time to send the password.

Try dropping the custom `Please authenticate` banner.

Answer (score 1):

I reply as new answer because I can't comment up there.

Well after two days working on that issue I see the problem is using # character for banner. If you switch to ., it works. This is because the hash character # is used as root, so RANCID believes is already logged on (No password to access)

Sharing knowledge :)